# Return in a recursive function doesn't break the loop

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm currently a student learning recursion and induction and i'm currently stuck.

I made a recursive algorithm which reversed my 2d array except when i has to return the map, it keeps continuing into itself untill it overloads.

Does anyone know how i can fix this? Cause i always thought a return into a loop would "break" the loop.

Here's the code:

```
var map = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [ 9, 5, 6, 4],
       [ 7, 8, 9, 2]];

function change()
{
var newmap = reverse2d(map, 0, 0, map.length - 1, map[0].length - 1);

var title = document.getElementById('title');
title.innerHTML = newmap.toString();
}

function reverse1d(map, first, last)
{
    if(first < last)
    {      
    var temp = map[first];
    map[first] = map[last];
    map[last] = temp;
    reverse(map, first + 1, last - 1);
    }
return map;
}

function reverse2d(map, xfirst, yfirst, xlast, ylast)
{
    if(!((xfirst == xlast) & (yfirst >= ylast)))
    {
        var temp = map[xfirst][yfirst];
        map[xfirst][yfirst] = map[xlast][ylast];
        map[xlast][ylast] = temp;

        if(ylast < 1)
        {
             var temp2 = yfirst;
             yfirst = ylast;
             ylast = temp2;
             reverse2d(map, xfirst + 1, yfirst, xlast - 1, ylast);
        }   

        reverse2d(map, xfirst, yfirst +1, xlast, ylast -1 );

     }
     console.log('print this before returning map');
     return map;
}
```

In console i can see "print this before returning map" ALOT of times. So it doesn't jump out and paste the array into the title as specified.

If you want to try out the code i used JSfiddle.net to try it out with JQuery 1.6.4 and no wrap is

The title and button is as follows:

```
    <h1 id="title"> Should turn up here </h1>
    <input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Do it" onclick="change()"/>
```

I hope anyone can help me

Comment: It would be helpful to see what the values are for xfirst, xlast, yfirst & ylast in each call to `reverse2d`.

Comment: It stats with xfirst, yfirst as 0,0 and xlast, ylast as the end of the array in this one it's 2,3. the first one adds up by 0,1 to 0,2 to 0,3 then going to 1,0 and 1,1 and 1,2. While the other one counts down as 2,3 to 2,2 to 2,1 to 2,0 to 1,3 to 1,2. When the IF statement is met, that is if both X are equal and yfirst >= ylast that means it's halfway. 

Then it runs into the return, goes back to the last routine and keeps going. I need it to stop and return map to where it shows it in the title like in the "change"  function.
Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/c6z0sm53/

Comment: I think you want to put an `else` before the second recursive call.

Comment: In the first condition statement of the function `reverse2d`  you have you have a single `&`  should that not be a logical And `&&`